# can't connect a local database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I can not connect a local database for Windows Forms project. To connect to the database I use the following algorithm:

**Project -> Add New Item -> Service-based Database**

after selecting **Service-based Database** I receive an error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The Server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is  correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.( provider:SQL Network interfaces,error:26 - Error Locating Srever/instance Specified)
```

I tried to connect

**Project -> Add New Data Source -> Database -> Dataset -> Microsoft SQL Server**

Everything worked out. Access to the database is. If I try to create **Microsoft SQL Server Database File**, I get an error

```
Login failed for user
```

Using **Microsoft Visual Studio 2017**, **SQL Express Server 2017**. What's the problem?

Comment: I study c# one months. I did not know that i can connect with ado. net :(

Comment: It's possible that the localdb instance of your computer is offline. Try to open up an elevated (administrator) CMD and run `sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb`. If that works, you should be able to then add a new database

Comment: Please make sure you service is running. Open Run and enter `services.msc`.

Comment: I run the command `sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb` in command line. I received a message `LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started`. I checked out the servic processes for sql . They all work.